# Find the DOM element containing a specific offset with jQuery or plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am paging an HTML page. In order to compute the page break offsets more efficiently, I was wondering if it is possible to get the element containing a certain coordinate offset from the beginning of the page.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help,
Cheers!

Comment: Is there any specific element you're targeting? Could you put together a sample structure?

Comment: I am not targeting a specific element, but the HTML files I've been working on mostly contain P's, IMG's and A's, they're all top-level siblings and do not overlap each other, nothing fancy.

My strategy so far has been to enumerate all the elements in the body and compute their offsets and check if they fall on a page boundary (I know how large the view is). I can go from elements to offsets, I was just wondering if the going from offsets to elements is somehow possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var offset = 100; 
$(document.body).find('[offsetTop = '+offset']');
```

or

```
var offset = 100;
$("body *").filter(function () {
   return this.offsetTop == offset;
});
```

since you said they're all top level elements, the following should also work:

```
$(document.body).children().filter(function () {
   return this.offsetTop == offset;
});
```

You can also `$(this).offset()` to get the offsets. Using the `offsetTop` property only gets the offset from the parent I believe. But it may not matter since they are all top level elements.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

I guess I could do this.offsetTop >= offset to find the first element after a certain offset, right?

Comment: @Engin Kurutepe: Well, it will return all of the elements that match that condition, not just the first. But essentially, yes - you can put any condition there. Also, I'm not sure if they will be returned in order (according to the offset), so you should get that out so you aren't using the first element in the jQuery array assuming it's the first element that satisfies that condition (although it may well be).